# Java split by a successive character

Tags: java, string, split

I have the following example, to explain better what i'm trying to do:

```
String text = "a,b,,,,c,,";
String[] split = text.split(",");
for(int i=0;i<split.length;i++){
    System.out.println("I = "+i+" "+split[i]);
}
```

The output is:

```
I = 0 a

I = 1 b

I = 2 

I = 3 

I = 4 

I = 5 c
```

But, what i want is to get an array of size 8, containing also:

```
I = 6 

I = 7
```

Of course, the last 2 elements will be empty strings, but it is essential for me to get them. Also, i think it's logical to have them. I mean, if i had:

```
String text = "a,b,,,,c,,d";
```

The result would be an array of size 8 and i don't think there is a big difference between the 2 examples.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
String[] split = text.split(",", -1);
```

This behavior actually looks tricky but it is actually explained (not very well IMHO, that said) in the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

> If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as
>   possible and the array can have any length

The problem with `text.split(",")` is that it's equivalent to `text.split(",", 0)`. Using a 0 limit, as explained in the documentation:

> If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as
>   possible, the array can have any length, and **trailing empty strings
>   will be discarded**.

You definitely do not want the empty strings to be discarded.

Comment: Wow. I didn't think I could learn something new about such a basic thing as `String#split`. I was wrong. Both the question and the answer were hugely educational. That said, offering the user *explanation* would take a good answer and make it great.

Comment: Thank you, it works great! I've programmed applications in java for about 3 years, but it seems like there are always new things to learn, even if they seem simple at first sight.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I just had this problem last week and this worked. I actually don't understand very well why/how this works and the documentation is not very clear about it

Answer (score 0):

I prefer (if you can use external libraries):

`String[] split = StringUtils.splitPreserveAllTokens(text, ',');`

For the most part the `StringUtils` library tends to be just that little bit more efficient than the default java implementation because... well, hey, that's why Apache bothered writing it. Plus, on the face of it, it's clear what this split is doing from the method name, whereas at first glance a regular string split with a -1 limit might not be.